# Find the Start of Heap using lld and s2wasm

Tags: memory-management, heap-memory, webassembly

I am compiling from C to WebAssembly using `clang -> llc -> s2wasm` and also `clang -> lld`. Because there is no c library supplied, I wrote my own allocator. But I am not sure what the best way is to find the beginning of free memory.

Both lld and s2wasm seem to have the memory layout: `| globals | stack | free memory |`. The stack pointer using s2wasm is at a memory address, using lld it is in a global (which is not accessible from C?).

A way that I found is to read the stackpointer at the beginning of wasm execution using this hack:

```c
int stacktop()
{
  int a;
  return (int)(&a+1);
}
```

This creates a local variable, which does not reside in linear memory and takes the address of it. To generate an address, the compiler puts it on the in-memory stack.

I am using the returned value as the beginning of my heap. Is there a more elegant and future-proof way to find the free memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get address of `__heap_base` symbol created by lld:

```
$ cat wasm-heap.c
extern unsigned char __heap_base;

__attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) 
void * get_heap_base(void) {
  return &__heap_base;
}
```

This would return the same value as `__heap_base` WASM variable exported to JavaScript:

```
$ cat wasm-heap.js
var imports = {memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({initial:2})};
const module = new WebAssembly.Module(read('wasm-heap.wasm', 'binary'));
const instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(module, { "env" : imports }).exports;
var u8_data = new Uint8Array(imports["memory"]["buffer"]);

print("Heap base in WASM: " + instance.get_heap_base());
print("Heap base exported to JS: " + instance.__heap_base);

$ js52 wasm-heap.js
Heap base in WASM: 66560
Heap base exported to JS: 66560
```

Answer (score 4):

lld creates a C symbol called `__heap_base` which points to the base of the heap.   It also exports this as a wasm global so the embedder can know where the heap starts.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how to access it. Clang does not know the symbol, so when I try to define it using `extern const uint32_t __heap_base`. clang creates a global but inserts just `i32.const 0, i32.load offset=4294967295` in the code. Using clang 6.0.0.

Comment: lld creates this symbol at link time.   Clang should generate relocation in the code and lld should replace it at link time.

Comment: OK. I have not managed to access it yet. Clang should probably create a global, which it doesn't. I will try to get to the bottom of this at a later time.

Comment: At compile time its just an unknown external symbol.  Its not until link time that the symbol exists so clang should not need to know anything about it.  I'm not sure what you mean by "clang should create a global".  Perhaps you mean it should be declared in a C header somewhere?

Comment: also some may find setting `-Clink-arg=--export=__heap_base` flag helpful for lld if you use external memory allocator.